# How to Switch from NativeApp to WebView when using Appium and RubyGems

Tags: android, webview, rubygems, appium

I am testing an Android hybrid app with selenium, appium, and RubyGems.  When I try to click on an image on the page using

```
element = driver.find_element(:id => "image0")
element.click
```

I receive an error saying it cannot find the object.  I then learned that I need to switch from Native App to WebView.  When I try switching to Webview

```
driver.switch_to.window("WEBVIEW")
```

I receive an error saying "...Not yet implemented..."

So how do I switch to Web so I can click on the webelement and then switch back to Native_App using RubyGems?

Added...
When I try 
    driver.switch_to.context("WebView")
I receive the error
undefined method `context' for # (NoMethodError)

Any idea why I would receive the context error?

[image]

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'uri'
require 'appium_lib'
require_relative 'SDK_Navigation'

mySampleApp = SampleApp.new
myNavigation = Navigation.new
myProducts = Products.new
myProductEditor = ProductEditor.new

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.android
caps['deviceName'] = 'fegero'
caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
caps['app'] = 'C:\Users\ScottFeger\Downloads\SampleApp_1105.apk'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(
  :remote,
  :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub",
  :desired_capabilities => caps)

mySampleApp.PickImagebtn(driver)
mySampleApp.SelectAlbum(driver, "All Photos")
mySampleApp.SelectImage(driver,"bob")
myNavigation.SelectParent(driver, "Home & Office")
myNavigation.SelectChild(driver, "Home Decor")
myProducts.SelectProduct(driver,"Coasters")
myProductEditor.AddPhoto(driver)


#================================================================
#WEBVIEW - Where my problem begins
#driver.execute_script 'mobile: tap', x: 150 , y: 300 // WORKS

driver.available_context
driver.switch_to.context("WebView")

#Click on an image
element = driver.find_element(:id => "image0")
element.click
```

Comment: I did try changing .window to .context, but I ended up getting an error     undefined method `context' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::TargetLocator:0x000000050f8d40> (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your block :

```
driver.available_context
driver.switch_to.context("WebView")
```

Probably the correct way to do it as the [docs](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/hybrid.md) suggests is :

```
Given(/^I switch to webview$/) do
    webview = @driver.contexts.last
    @driver.switch_to.context(webview)
end
```

Also make sure you switch to webview before trying to access any element on it and switch out of it before trying to access elements out of it.

```
Given(/^I switch out of webview$/) do
    @driver.switch_to.context(@driver.contexts.first)
end
```

Comment: I added a screenshot of the app because I received the undefined method 'context' error again. I must be missing something.

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/TargetLocator does understanding this helps?

Comment: I finally had time to review your comments and I must not be getting it.  I added my code above so hopefully you can help me out.  Everything works correctly until I get to the bottom of the page.  Is there something I need to declare, or some other line of code I'm missing?  Thanks.

Comment: @user3531858 : have updated my answer to switch context to webview and out of it